# Rewriting a URL causing a 400 Bad Request

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get around an HTTP 400 Bad Request with Apache that is caused when this URL is accessed (actual domain redacted):

`http://example.com/nw/f/RUD/E.enc<space>`

The URL ends with an actual space character, thus giving an HTTP 400 Bad Request. I cannot get the clients requesting this to remove the space in the URL, so I need to rewrite the URL without a space.

I've tried some RewriteRules, like this one (after enabling the RewriteEngine):

`RewriteRule "^/nw/f/RUD/E(.*)$" /nw/f/RUD/E.enc [P]`

The RewriteRule has no effect and is still giving an HTTP 400.

It even happens when I escape the space character instead of using the wildcard in the rule. Same thing if I try to replace the HTTP 400 error page to lead to the actual content (which wouldn't be ideal, since there's 4 different files).

How can I correctly rewrite the URL, removing the space on it, without getting HTTP 400?

Comment: Is the `[P]` flag really correct here, are you proxying the request somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteRule` produces a redirect loop as `.../E.enc<space>` and `.../E.enc` both match `.../E(.*)$`.
Better use a `[R]`edirect, though proxying also works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/nw/f/RUD/E\.enc $" /nw/f/RUD/E.enc [R,L]
```

or shorter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^(/nw/f/RUD/E\.enc) $" $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: With your `RewriteRule` (and setting `ProxyTimeout` to 10 seconds) I get an 502 Proxy Error :)

Comment: Sounds like there is more to this than you are telling us - what proxy?

Comment: The proxy [`[P]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) in your `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried both of these. They're closer, but I'm still getting HTTP 400.